# SQL query to return 0 or 1 as one record from result of two queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, union

I have a RunHistory table, where process run result logs in. Process is either running thru a scheduler where it logs in RunInstance as Numeric, but if run manually, then it logs in 'MANUAL'
I need a query to check if the process ran today (GetDate()) regardless it was MANUAL or thru scheduler. If it ran, then query should return 1 else 0 as one single record. I have created temp table and UNION query to demo the issue.

```
create table #RunHistory
    (
    [RunId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [ReportDate] [date] NOT NULL,
    [RunInstance] [varchar](6) NOT NULL,
    [RunStartTime] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [RunEndTime] [datetime] NULL,
    )
    
INSERT INTO #RunHistory
           ([ReportDate]
           ,[RunInstance]
           ,[RunStartTime]
           ,[RunEndTime])
     VALUES
           ('2020-07-29'
           ,'1200'
           ,'2020-07-29 12:44:13.340'
           ,'2020-07-29 12:44:25.313')
    INSERT INTO #RunHistory
           ([ReportDate]
           ,[RunInstance]
           ,[RunStartTime]
           ,[RunEndTime])
     VALUES
           ('2020-07-29'
           ,'MANUAL'
           ,'2020-07-29 12:36:51.117'
           ,'2020-07-29 12:41:10.720')

           --if both ran returing 1 then it works fine
    SELECT RESULT 
    FROM  
    (
    SELECT CASE WHEN  COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS RESULT
    FROM #RunHistory
    WHERE RunEndTime IS NOT NULL AND RunInstance IS NOT NULL
        AND (ISNUMERIC(RunInstance) > 0)
        AND CONVERT(TINYINT,LEFT(RunInstance,2)) >= 8 
        AND CONVERT(DATE,#RunHistory.ReportDate) =  CONVERT(DATE,Getdate())
    UNION
    SELECT CASE WHEN  COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS RESULT
    FROM #RunHistory
    WHERE RunEndTime IS NOT NULL AND RunInstance IS NOT NULL
        AND RunInstance ='MANUAL'
        AND CONVERT(DATE,#RunHistory.ReportDate) =  CONVERT(DATE,Getdate())
    ) as z
    
    --if one of then returns 0 as result, then two records are returned. I just want if one of the records is 1, then return 1
    SELECT RESULT 
    FROM  
    (
    SELECT 0 AS RESULT
    FROM #RunHistory
    WHERE RunEndTime IS NOT NULL AND RunInstance IS NOT NULL
        AND (ISNUMERIC(RunInstance) > 0)
        AND CONVERT(TINYINT,LEFT(RunInstance,2)) >= 8 
        AND CONVERT(DATE,#RunHistory.ReportDate) =  CONVERT(DATE,Getdate())
    UNION
    SELECT CASE WHEN  COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS RESULT
    FROM #RunHistory
    WHERE RunEndTime IS NOT NULL AND RunInstance IS NOT NULL
        AND RunInstance ='MANUAL'
        AND CONVERT(DATE,#RunHistory.ReportDate) =  CONVERT(DATE,Getdate())
    ) as z
```

Don't know if I really need a UNION or somehow both conditions can be combined in one query OR an outer query is required.

Comment: Your query implements logic that you do not describe, such as the comparison to `8`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to restrict by `RunInstance` if it doesn't matter whether it was manual or not:

```
select case when count(1) > 0 then 1 else 0 end result
from #RunHistory
where RunEndTime is not null
and   RunInstance is not null
and   convert(date,ReportDate) = convert(date,getdate())
```

If you do need to union multiple queries, then you can get the maximum result:

```
select max(result)
from (
    SELECT 0 AS RESULT
    FROM #RunHistory
    WHERE RunEndTime IS NOT NULL AND RunInstance IS NOT NULL
        AND (ISNUMERIC(RunInstance) > 0)
        AND CONVERT(TINYINT,LEFT(RunInstance,2)) >= 8 
        AND CONVERT(DATE,ReportDate) =  CONVERT(DATE,Getdate())
    UNION
    SELECT CASE WHEN  COUNT(*) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS RESULT
    FROM #RunHistory
    WHERE RunEndTime IS NOT NULL AND RunInstance IS NOT NULL
        AND RunInstance ='MANUAL'
        AND CONVERT(DATE,ReportDate) =  CONVERT(DATE,Getdate())
) as z
```